# How Can I make it able to solve with LALR(1)

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, shift-reduce-conflict

```
*X-> Ya| cYb | Zb | cZa
Y-> q | Eplison | XaZ
Z-> f | q*
```

I've done with LR(1) parsing table and also proved that this is not LALR(1) but is there any way to make it able so that I can make LALR(1) for this?

Comment: Were the * before X and the * after q meant as actual symbols, or was the idea to bold the grammar?

Comment: That was for doing bold, but didn't happened.

Comment: I know in Grammer this could be big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the ambiguity of the grammar, because LALR parser work just for unambigous grammars.

## The problems is:

- with an LALR(1) parser when we read q (for your grammar) we can't understand where derive, y or z, so we must solve this problem

## Example

let the string "qa" be the input string for the grammar:
we have two cases, the first:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      terminal       |     character    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |         q        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|           q         |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|           y         |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|           ya        |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|           x         |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

and the second :

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      terminal       |     character    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |         q        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|           q         |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|           z         |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|           za        |                  | <--- there your parser stuck
|---------------------|------------------|
```

## Solution

We must have one q in our grammar.
So our y and z become:

[image]

so now always for the string "qa":

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      terminal       |     character    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |         q        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|           q         |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|           D         |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|           Da        |                  |<--- there your parser stuck
|---------------------|------------------|
```

so our parser stuck again?
unfortunately yes, because now d is present in both y and z, so we can try to unify them like this:

[image]

and change x like this:

[image]

it's immediately understandable that also this production is ambigious, so the conclusion is that evry LALR parser can be transformed into an LR parser but not vice versa

Comment: Let me try for solve this using LALR(1), well thanks for answering.

Comment: Can you elaborate this? What you did? You just factored q and made a new production D->q

Comment: i'm doing a correction, if you see now there is always reduce/reduce conflict but with D

Comment: the correction is done, but maybe is not the
the result you wanted lol

Comment: Gladly, I would like to tell you that it worked for me. Thank you Soo much. Approved your answer as right answer. :)

Comment: In the last modified Grammer what about Z and D?? Z-> ???? And D-> ????

Comment: D -> q* (i wrote it on the top) and Z should be y , so XaY

Comment: D is correct but i had unify Z Y IN Y  so Y is, Y -> D | Espsilon | XaY | f (see the the production now, corrected the mistake)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Last question is " c q a a f" be generated by the Grammer??

Comment: there are not white space in the grammar so the string " c q a a f" can't be generated instead "cqaaf" also not because with the your grammar the string after parsing is cYaaZ that's not derivable, instead with my grammar you get cDaaY that's also not parsable